# echo with attribute name for query purposes php pdo

Tags: php, pdo, attributes, echo

```
<form method="POST" action="include/crud.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                        <?php
                        foreach (LoadAnouncements() as $value){
                            /*echo "<div id='bb'></div>";*/
                            echo "<hr/>";
                            echo $value['searchresultwhat'];
                            echo "<br/>\n";
                            echo $value['searchresultwhen'];
                            echo "<br/>\n";
                            echo $value['searchresultwhere'];
                            echo "<hr/>";
                            /*echo "<div id='bb'></div>";*/

                        }
                    ?>
                    </form>
```

I have this form that show an echo is there a way that I can add the attribute `name` in this echo so I can use it to query the database? I search for ideas if putting attribute to echo is possible but I haven't found anything yet any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Does `LoadAnouncements()` it return an object?

Comment: array sir..is there a way i can use one echo here to query the database by adding attribute name to it?

Comment: i cant figure out what your trying to say can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking it?

```
<input type="text" name="searchresultwhat[]" value="<?php echo $value['searchresultwhat']; ?>" />

<input type="text" name="searchresultwhen[]" value="<?php echo $value['searchresultwhen']; ?>" />

<input type="text" name="searchresultwhere[]" value="<?php echo $value['searchresultwhere']; ?>" />
```

Edited

```
      <?php
        echo '<table>';
        echo '<tr><th>What </th><th> When</th><th> Where</th><tr>';
         foreach (LoadAnouncements() as $value){
           echo "<tr><td><a href='anotherPage.php?searchresultwhat=".$value['searchresultwhat']."&searchresultwhen=".$value['searchresultwhat']."&searchresultwhere=".$value['searchresultwhat'].">".$value['searchresultwhat']."</a></td>
                 <td><a href='anotherPage.php?searchresultwhat=".$value['searchresultwhat']."&searchresultwhen=".$value['searchresultwhat']."&searchresultwhere=".$value['searchresultwhat'].">"$value['searchresultwhen']."</a></td>
                 <td><a href='anotherPage.php?searchresultwhat=".$value['searchresultwhat']."&searchresultwhen=".$value['searchresultwhat']."&searchresultwhere=".$value['searchresultwhere'].">".$value['searchresultwhere']."</a></td>

                </tr>";

          }
        echo '</table>';
     ?>
```

Comment: i dont want to use input because i want it to like like plain text only and boxes

Comment: without inputs how will you post the datas to action page? better you can use text to type and show the values in div element!

Comment: i see what you are trying to say so it is not possible?any other way to do it like the way i want it?how to query database using other means?

Comment: can u say what exactly the input and output will be?

Comment: when my page load i will get the last 5 entry in the announcement table and i will show it as echo those echo then if i click 1 echo i want to go to another page and view all the details about that event so i need to query the database for that event to view other details

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to add attribute to certain value in PHP? But you can't do it because `$value['searchresultwhat']` and others of the kind are simple strings - as is! They can't send separated data (or attributes) with themself.

**EDIT:**
You can send seprated data about certain value using array:

```
$value['searchresultwhat'] = array("name", "value");
$value['searchresultwhen'] = array("name2", "2014-09-01");
$value['searchresultwhere'] = array("name3", "kittens");

echo $value['searchresultwhat'][0] . " is " . $value['searchresultwhat'][1];
echo $value['searchresultwhen'][0] . " = " . $value['searchresultwhen'][1];
echo $value['searchresultwhere'][0] . " has " . $value['searchresultwhere'][1];
```